# Using javascript how to target all HTML list elements which have been created by a loop of JSP scriplets

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, scriptlet

If I target list item to change the background-color using java script only first occurrence of list item will be affected and remaining 3  list items will not be affected

In the  code below assume that x=5, then we will get 4 list items. Now in the javascript if i write `document.getElementsByClassName("Booking-occupant").style.ba‌​ckground="green"` only first list item will get background color to be green but not remaining 3 list items. What code should I write in JAVASCRIPT so that all list items will get background color to be green for example??

```
<%int x=tourism.getMax_seats();
    while(x>1){


%>
<li class="Booking-occupant" id="man">
    <span class="Booking-seatAvailable">
        <span class="u-visuallyHidden">Available seat</span>
    </span>
</li>
<%
    x--;
    } %>
```

Comment: "This code"... Which code?

Comment: Items that share the same class name can be treated as a group.

Comment: Where is your javascript code?

Comment: In the above code assume that x=5, then we will get 4 list items. Now in the javascript if i  write document.getElementsByClassName("Booking-occupant").style.background="green" only first list item will get background color to be green but not remaining 3 list items. How to resolve this??